# gvim copy to and paste from external clipboard (Windows 7) using y and p keys?

Tags: vim

My current gvim copy to and paste from external clipboard is set to **ctrl+y** and **ctrl+p** based on a tip I've found on the Internet last year. Is there a way to change these keys to **y** and **p** using vim's default yank and paste keys? This way, I don't have to select + copy the text twice (once for vim memory and another for clipboard memory).

I've tried to find the answer on the Internet, but wasn't able to find the answer to my exact problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create mapping, there is an alternative, however I don't have any windows system, so I cannot test it on win7, if it works. At least it works for gvim.

There is an option `clipboard`, you can set `unnamedplus`, to let vim use `+` as "default" register.

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

`:h 'clipboard'` to check details.

Comment: It's half way there, I was able to paste from Windows Clipboard to vim using p key, but I can't copy text from vim to Windows Clipboard using y key.

Comment: I see seting this command will also disable some yank combination keys, like copying from current location to end of file with y$

Answer (score 2):

This works on my windows gvim...

`:map y "+Y`

`:map p "+gP`

Personally, I just always type `"+gP` when I want to clipboard paste.  It's not a hard muscle memory.

Comment: why big `Y` in first mapping?

Comment: The docs say it's a synonym for `y`, and when I used `y`, I got weird behavior (infinite loop perhaps?)

Comment: that's why we should use `nnoremap` or `vnoremap`

Comment: Although this does work, looks like it only works with Windows Clipboard. Vim's default yank key + combination keys don't working anymore. For example, to copy from current location to the end of line: y$